# Trying to parse a string to a double, getting "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: c#, string

I need to parse a string from a datatable into a double. I have a datatable (dt) and it has different columns, and each of these columns are converted to strings with the `.ToString()` method. However, when I try to output the latitude and longitude of the data, I get an error "Input string was not in a correct format." So I guess my main question is, how do you parse text from an object converted to a string using the `.ToString()` method..

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;

namespace SalesMap
{
    class SalesMap
    {
        private static DataTable InitData1()
        {
            //Datatable for entire list of zipcodes
            DataTable datat = new DataTable("DATA");
            DataColumn state = new DataColumn();
            DataColumn county = new DataColumn();
            DataColumn statecounty = new DataColumn();
            DataColumn latitude = new DataColumn();
            DataColumn longitude = new DataColumn();
            DataColumn salesperson = new DataColumn();

            //Add the columns to the datatable
            datat.Columns.Add(state);
            datat.Columns.Add(county);
            datat.Columns.Add(statecounty);
            datat.Columns.Add(latitude);
            datat.Columns.Add(longitude);
            datat.Columns.Add(salesperson);

            return datat;
        }       

        private static String InitPath()
        {
            string path = "C:/Documents and Settings/Andre/Desktop/salesmapdata/MapPointCountyLatLong.csv";
            return path;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = InitData1();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(InitPath());
                String csvData = string.Empty;

                while ((csvData = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    String[] data = csvData.Split(',');
                    //dt.Rows.Add(data);
                    DataRow newRow1 = dt.NewRow();
                    newRow1[0] = data[0].ToString(); //state
                    newRow1[1] = data[1].ToString(); //county
                    newRow1[2] = data[2].ToString(); //state|county
                    newRow1[3] = data[3].ToString(); //latitude
                    newRow1[4] = data[4].ToString(); //longitude
                    newRow1[5] = data[5].ToString(); //salesperson
                    dt.Rows.Add(newRow1);

                    Console.WriteLine("Row added for: dt");
                }

                foreach (DataRow row1 in dt.Rows)
                {
                    double latitude1 = Double.Parse(row1[3].ToString());
                    double longitude1 = Double.Parse(row1[4].ToString());

                    if (row1[5].ToString() != "UNKNOWN" || row1[5].ToString() != "SALESMAN")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(latitude1);
                        Console.WriteLine(longitude1);
                    }
                }

                dt.WriteXml(@"c:\test\dt1.xml");
                sr.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\test\error.txt");
                sw.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That really depends on what the values are for `row1[3]` and `row1[4]`.  Can you give us a sample of you csv?

Comment: What you have is correct, as long as the data you are working with can actually be parsed to a Double. Sample data would help diagnose.

Comment: Definitely need the sample data. It could be that your lat/long values have some of the symbols (for degrees, minutes, seconds, etc).

Comment: `String[] data = csvData.Split(',');` is not anywhere near good enough to parse a CSV file.  What if I have a comma in quotes (which is perfectly valid)?  Your code breaks.  There are libraries for this, if it were as easy as `string.Split` they wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when reading data from CSV file, you don't need to call `data[x].ToString()` on each array element, since they are already strings.

Few potential issues you might have with Double.Parse calls:

1. The data in your CSV file is really in the wrong format (maybe you
   misplaced the column numbers, or data might have an additional symbols that couldn't be parsed, like Tim mentioned in his comment).
2. You have empty strings in your columns. Those cannot be parsed to double. You need to check that first, using `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()` or something similar.
3. Your culture is wrong. You might have latitude and longitude values that use decimal point in your CSV file, but your current thread culture might be using comma as decimal separator. There's an [overload of `Decimal.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7xswkc6.aspx) that accepts Culture as parameter (you could supply [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) or any other [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks, I did not go around the headers, so it was erroring out because it was actually a string and not a double. Thanks!

Comment: Hehe, or 4. Trying to parse the header... No problem.